# How to create struct from array loop key value

Tags: json, loops, go, struct, foreach

Can anyone tell me how to create multiple struct from a array.

exemple:

```
{
   "key1": [
      {
         "subkey1": "", 
         "subkey2": ""
      },
      {
         "subkey1": "" 
      }
   ]
   "key2": [
      {
         "subkey1": "", 
         "subkey2": ""
      }
   ]
}
```

Voilà, I need to create a struct foreach key and attach the second struct based on subkey.

Comment: Are you asking how to decode the JSON document in the question to Go types?

Comment: yes, i got the json in a separate file,
i need to read the file and print the content in json format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way in which you can do what you want is this :

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

var input = `{
    "key1": [
       {
          "subkey1": "Apple", 
          "subkey2": "Dog"
       },
       {
          "subkey1": "Bear" 
       }
    ],
    "key2": [
       {
          "subkey1": "Monkey", 
          "subkey2": "Turtle"
       }
    ]
 }`

var response map[string][]map[string]string

func main() {
    var err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &response)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err.Error())
    }
    for k, v := range response {
        fmt.Printf("Key: %s : | Value : %v\n", k, v)
    }

    for _, v := range response["key1"] {
        fmt.Println(v["subkey1"])
    }
    }
```

Which will print :

```
    Key: key2 : | Value : [map[subkey1:Monkey subkey2:Turtle]]
    Key: key1 : | Value : [map[subkey1:Apple subkey2:Dog] map[subkey1:Bear]]
    Apple
    Bear
```

You can also use structs as the value in the dictionaries if you want :

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

var input = `{
    "key1": [
       {
          "subkey1": "Apple", 
          "subkey2": "Dog"
       },
       {
          "subkey1": "Bear" 
       }
    ],
    "key2": [
       {
          "subkey1": "Monkey", 
          "subkey2": "Turtle"
       }
    ]
 }`

type YourStruct struct {
    Subkey1 string `json:"subkey1"`
    Subkey2 string `json:"subkey2"`
}

var response map[string][]YourStruct

func main() {
    var err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &response)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err.Error())
    }
    for k, v := range response {
        fmt.Printf("Key: %s : | Value : %v\n", k, v)
    }

    for _, v := range response["key1"] {
        fmt.Println(v.Subkey1)
    }
}
```

Which will print :

```
[~/Projects/GoSO]@somewhere #> go run main.go 
Key: key1 : | Value : [{Apple Dog} {Bear }]
Key: key2 : | Value : [{Monkey Turtle}]
Apple
Bear
```

Comment: thanks you for your answer Matias Barrios.